# hibernate query cache specify cache duration

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, caching

below is how i do query cache

```
   getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(true);
   List<IssSection> result = (List<IssSection>) getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(crit);
   getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(false);
```

may i know how to specify duration of maximum time to cache this method? let say i want to clear cache after 5 mins expirated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate does not provide an interface for controlling specifics of the cache such as you request.

Instead, you have to choose a cache implementation that provides that functionality, and configure it appropriately.

E.g. you can use [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html) and configure it like so:

```
<cache
    name="com.somecompany.someproject.domain.Country"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    eternal="false"
    **timeToIdleSeconds="300"**
    **timeToLiveSeconds="600"**
    overflowToDisk="true"
/>
```

The two highlighted attributes above illustrate how you may configure the duration of cached time for the cached elements.

Answer (score 2):

> May I know how to specify duration of maximum time to cache this method?

You would have to choose a L2 cache provider supporting expiration (EHCache, OSCache, JCS) and to **configure** the cache region for this particular request.